# Whats difference between using parentheses and not using them on address

Tags: php, laravel

Version without parentheses:

```
Route::get('/read', function(){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    echo $user->address->name;  // <- this line
});
```

Version with parentheses:

```
Route::get('/delete', function(){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $user->address()->delete();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the first one:

```
$user->address->name;
```

returns an eloquent instance so you can get the properties out of it, and the second:

```
$user->address()->delete();
```

returns a `Query Builder` instance on which you can perform SQL queries as you already do, so it will delete the row from the database.

Comment: So you saying , if i want to perform SQL queries, i'll have to use parentheses?